# Install dll into 2 targets (paths) with qmake

Tags: c++, qt, dll, installation, qmake

Have following qt pro file:

```
CONFIG      += plugin debug_and_release
TARGET      = $$qtLibraryTarget(WidgetBoxPlugin)
TEMPLATE    = lib
...
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/designer
creator_target.path = $$[QTCREATOR_BIN_PATH]/plugins/designer
INSTALLS    += target creator_target
```

And resulted dll file was copied into 2 paths (targets). Now it does not work for some reason: qmake does not generate install (copy) script for 2nd target (QTCREATOR_BIN_PATH is set). How to write 2nd install correctly so dll being installed into 2 destinations?

Full project: https://github.com/akontsevich/WidgetBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got suggestion here:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/66090/qmake-does-not-generate-2nd-install-target-in-makefile/3#

According to documentation (https://wiki.qt.io/QMake-top-level-srcdir-and-builddir) correct build dir macro is $$OUT_PWD, so correct installation code is:

```
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/designer

creator_target.name = Copying the target dll to Qt Creator plugins directory as well
creator_target.input = $qtLbraryTarget(WidgetBoxPlugin)
creator_target.path  = $$(QTCREATOR_BIN_PATH)/plugins/designer
creator_target.CONFIG += no_check_exist
creator_target.output = WidgetBoxPlugin.dll
creator_target.files = $$OUT_PWD/release/WidgetBoxPlugin.dll
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += creator_target

INSTALLS += target creator_target
```

Only strange why [] brackets only work for target and () are necessary for creator_target?

Answer (score 1):

> How to write a copy of my project target correctly so dll being installed
>   into 2 destinations?

You can try to create a new target path with `QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS`:

http://blog.qt.io/blog/2008/04/16/the-power-of-qmake/

```
creator_target.name = Copying the target dll to Qt Creator plugins directory as well
creator_target.input = $$qtLibraryTarget(WidgetBoxPlugin)
creator_target.path  = $$[QTCREATOR_BIN_PATH]/plugins/designer
creator_target.CONFIG += target_predeps no_link
creator_target.output = WidgetBoxPlugin.dll
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += creator_target

INSTALLS += creator_target
```

The other and maybe simpler way is to always attempt to copy post build but with xcopy /D/Y command syntax we can avoid copying if target exists:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += xcopy /d/y $$qtLibraryTarget(WidgetBoxPlugin) ${QTCREATOR_BIN_PATH}/plugins/designer
```

The problem with this command is to correctly escape the input yet it is more widely known here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=QMAKE_POST_LINK

Comment: Я тоже пробую разные способы решения проблемы, но у меня нет вашего проекта. С обоими способами довольно просто всё. Это то, что я лично делаю для решения проблемы.

Comment: You may look my project here: https://github.com/akontsevich/WidgetBox thought pro content is enough.

Comment: I glanced at the project and assume hat QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS should work like that.

Comment: AlexanderVX, above does not work as well: `warning: Compiler: creator_target: No output file specified` on qmake.

Comment: Think this is some bug in qmake: my variant should work, and Yours too. But qmake does not generate correct install in Makefile for some reason. Worked for me first time I created it.

Comment: http://blog.qt.io/blog/author/ashaw/ Andy Shaw is a very knowledgeable guy and he is the one who actually suggested me many useful things: we bought commercial Qt. I believe you can still ask him via email or so. I personally am can mostly do 'quick and dirty' reviews of SO questions, too many distractions. I guess your project shows you do useful work for Qt community so the community should help.

Comment: How to send him letter?

Comment: need to register there. Sent bugreport for now: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52580

Comment: I read that bug thread. What would be the final complete solution then?

Comment: QMAKE_POST_LINK is the other way. So I added it back to the answer. While debugging your .pro file you can look at resulting make file and/or Qt Creator / General Messages output tab. I used it like:         QMAKE_POST_LINK += xcopy /d/y $${PWD_WIN}\\$${FILE} $${DESTDIR_WIN}$$escape_expand(\\n\\t)